# all maxOccurs unbounded in XSD version 1.0

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I have an XML structure that looks like this:

```
<node>
  <!-- node contains a lot of optional property nodes, 
       and the order is random. -->
  <property2>value</property2>
  <property1>value</property1>
  <property4>value</property4>
  <property3>value</property3>

  <!-- node also contains 0-to-unbounded child elements 
       to simplify things, these are listed after the properties. -->
  <child> ... </child>
  <child> ... </child>
  <child> ... </child>
</node>
```

I understand that in XSD 1.1 I can validate this as follows:

```
<xs:all>
  <xs:element name="property1" minOccurs="0"/>
  <xs:element name="property2" minOccurs="0"/>
  <xs:element name="property3" minOccurs="0"/>
  <xs:element name="property4" minOccurs="0"/>
  ...

  <xs:element name="child" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
</xs:all>
```

**Unfortunately, I should do this in XSD 1.0.** (i.e. The consuming application does not support XSD 1.1.) However, XSD 1.0 does not allow `maxOccurs="unbounded"` restrictions for elements which defined in an `xs:all` node.

Not everything has to be validated strictly.

- But it's important that the property nodes are defined only once each (e.g. not multiple times `property3`).
- It's important that the order of appearance is not strict.
- It's important that the child nodes can appear more than once.

Answer (score 1):

If those properties have no substructure, consider making them attributes rather than elements; then you can have order insignificance.

Otherwise, state an ordering on the property elements and don't worry about it.  Never have I seen an ordering impose an undue burden on an application generating XML data.  Instead, it's always that an XSD designer sees no intrinsic need for ordering and fears imposing one arbitrarily.  In reality, however, a sequence works fine unless the order of elements is itself being used to convey information.  In all other cases, an XSD 1.0 `xs:sequence` will be fine.

Comment: It's a legacy problem really. There's not just one application, but there are multiple applications that interface using an agreed xml format (there are about 20 of those applications). These applications are maintained by different companies, and originally, when they were being developed, the xml format specs did not always define the same order for the properties. (e.g. Sometimes they were ordered in alphabetical order.) The central system doesn't mind in which order nodes are. So we do want to enforce an XSD to check node names and required fields. But we don't want to enforce new rules.

Comment: Understood.  Unfortunately, then, the situation has been allowed to develop to the point that your "important" constraints cannot simultaneously be checked in XSD 1.0.